# Reading ints line by line with different line length

Tags: c++, string, int, extract

I have this text file, each line represents the vertices of a polygon.

```
(-189, 102), (-62, 113), (-40, 56), (-105, -11)
(-692, 403), (-669, 308), (-572, 273)
(-750, 480), (750, 480), (750, -480), (-750, -480) 
(57, -218), (47, -270), (134, -366), (235, -366), (300, -260), (335, -182)
```

How can I read each vertex x and y and store them to int variables. Notice that each line can have different number of pairs.**Also I want to do it line by line so I know when a new polygon starts in the file.**

I am trying this to get every line but then what do I do to extract the ints from the line?

```
int main() {
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("input.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            //cout << line << '\n';
            stringstream stream(line);

        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you always have pair of two values. I would suggest to start from removing all special symbols such as '(', ')', ',', etc. Then it should be quite easy by using one of available tokenizers

Comment: @nosbor While I'd agree with your statement that the input should be simplified if possible, we can easily use a `sregex_iterator` to extract this information in its current format in C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38266802/2642059

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `line` correctly. You'll just need to establish a container (I'll be using `vector<vector<pair<int,int>> foo`.) Then you can just use a [`regex_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator/regex_iterator) to extract the information for you. I'd use something like this:

```
\s*,?\s*\(\s*([-0-9]+)\s*,\s*([-0-9]+)\s*\)
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/iL1fD7/1)

Then, once you've gotten `line` you can just use your regex something like this:

```
regex re(R"~(\s*,?\s*\(\s*([-0-9]+)\s*,\s*([-0-9]+)\s*\))~");
vector<pair<int, int>> temp;

transform(sregex_iterator(cbegin(line), cend(line), re), sregex_iterator(), back_inserter(temp), [](const auto& it) { return make_pair(stoi(it[1]), stoi(it[2])); });
foo.push_back(temp);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/l9J63y)

**EDIT:**

If you chose the simplest delimiting scheme, delimiting your input with white-space and new-lines, you could avoid the regex. This may be desirable, but you won't see any change in performance since almost any method can be written off with the file IO expense. None the less if you were given the input:

> -189 102 -62 113 -40 56 -105 -11
>   -692 403 -669 308 -572 273
>   -750 480 750 480 750 -480 -750 -480
>   57 -218 47 -270 134 -366 235 -366 300 -260 335 -182

Once you'd again gotten `line` you could do:

```
istringstream stream(line);
vector<pair<int, int>> temp;

for(pair<int, int> i; stream >> i.first >> i.second;) temp.push_back(i);
foo.push_back(temp);
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/ljMhAO)

Comment: if I simplify the input so that the numbers in each line are only seperated with a coma after every pair , can we simplify the code?

Comment: @GeorgeP White-space is the delimiter of choice in C++. But it won't simplify your code tremendously. I've edited my answer to demonstrate. The real ideal here would be to use .xml, but that would again require a regex or third party library to parse.